# pygatt fails during char_read() call when trying to connect RPI3B+ with Philips Hue lamp via BLE

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, iot, philips-hue

## Description

So, I try to connect to a Philips Hue lamp via BLE with my Raspberry Pi Model 3B+. Therefore I wrote the following python script using the `pygatt` library.

## Code

```py
import pygatt

ADDRESS_TYPE = pygatt.BLEAddressType.random
CHARACTERISTIC = '932c32bd-0002-47a2-835a-a8d455b859dd'

adapter = pygatt.GATTToolBackend()

try:
    adapter.start()
    devices = adapter.scan(run_as_root=True, timeout=3)
    for entry in devices:
        if entry['name'] == 'Hue Lamp':
            try:
                device = adapter.connect(entry['address'], address_type=ADDRESS_TYPE)
                device.char_write(CHARACTERISTIC, bytearray([0x00]), wait_for_response=False)
                value = device.char_read(CHARACTERISTIC)
                device.disconnect()
            except pygatt.exceptions.NotConnectedError:
                print('Failed to connect to %s' % entry['address'])
finally:
    adapter.stop()
```

## Behaviour of Code

When I run the script, it seems a connection is established successfully. The `char_write()` call should turn off the lamp but nothing happens. The `char_read()` call is raising an exception with the traceback stated below.

## Exception Traceback

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    value = device.char_read(CHARACTERISTIC)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pygatt/backends/gatttool/device.py", line 17, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pygatt/backends/gatttool/device.py", line 40, in char_read
    return self._backend.char_read(self, uuid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pygatt/backends/gatttool/gatttool.py", line 50, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pygatt/backends/gatttool/gatttool.py", line 593, in char_read
    self.sendline('char-read-uuid %s' % uuid)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 119, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pygatt/backends/gatttool/gatttool.py", line 191, in event
    self.wait(event, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pygatt/backends/gatttool/gatttool.py", line 157, in wait
    raise NotificationTimeout()
pygatt.exceptions.NotificationTimeout: None
```

## Note

I can read out the BLE characteristics of the lamp with `pygatt`. Also I can control the lamp via the NRF Connect Android app. When I write to the above characteristic the value `0x00` with the app, the lamp turns off as expected.

Comment: Is that on the phone with the app and with a bonded connection to the Philips Hue? You might get disconnected from another device. Try with another phone and the NRF Connect app to see if you succeed.